# How do I accurately represent this ElasticSearch query using NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api2, nest

## Background / Goal

I have a query in ElasticSearch where I'm using filters on a several fields (relatively small data set and we know exactly what values should be in those fields at the time we query). The idea is that we'll perform a full-text query but only after we've filtered on some selections as made by the user.

I'm putting ElasticSearch behind a WebAPI controller and figured it made sense to use NEST to accomplish the query.

## The query, in plain English

We have filters for several fields. Each inner filter is an or filter, but they're together as an AND.

In SQL, the pseudo-code equivalent would be `select * from table where foo in (1,2,3) AND bar in (4,5,6)`.

## Questions

- Can I simplify the way I'm thinking about this query, based on what you see below? Am I overlooking some basic approach? This seems heavy but I'm new to ES.
- How would I properly represent the query below in NEST syntax?
- Is NEST the best choice for this? Should I be using the ElasticSearch library instead and going lower level?

## The Query Text

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "or": [
                { "term": { "foo": "something" } },
                { "term": { "foo": "somethingElse" } }
              ]
            },
            {
              "or": [
                { "term": { "bar": "something" } },
                { "term": { "bar": "somethingElse" } }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "size": 100
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of task is quite simple and popular in ES.
You can represent it in NEST like following:

```
var rs = es.Search<dynamic>(s => s
            .Index("your_index").Type("your_type")
            .From(0).Size(100)
            .Query(q => q
                .Filtered(fq => fq
                    .Filter(ff => ff
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(
                                m1 => m1.Terms("foo", new string[] { "something", "somethingElse" }),
                                m2 => m2.Terms("bar", new string[] { "something", "somethingElse" })
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Query(qq => qq
                        .MatchAll()
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Some notes:

- I use filtered query to filter what I need first, then search stuffs later. In this case the it will filter for `foo in ("something", "somethingElse") AND bar in ("something", "somethingElse")`, then query all filtered results (`match_all`). You can change `match_all` to what you need. `filtered query` it's for best performance as ES will only need to evaluate scores of documents in `query` part (after filtered), not all documents.
- I use `terms` filter, which more simple and better performance than `or`. Default mode of `terms` is OR all input terms, you can refer more in document about available modes (AND, OR, PLAIN, ...).

Nest is best choice for .NET in my opinion as it designed for simple & easy to use purposes. I only used lower API if I want to use new features that Nest does not support at that time, or if Nest have bugs in functions I use.
You can refer here for a brief NEST tutorial: http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/writing-queries.html

Updated: Building bool filters dynamic:

```
var filters = new List<Nest.FilterContainer>();
filters.Add(Nest.Filter<dynamic>.Terms("foo", new string[] { "something", "somethingElse" }));
// ... more filter
```

then replace `.Bool(b => b.Must(...))` with `.Bool(b => b.Must(filters.ToArray()))`

Hope it help

Comment: This is a seriously helpful starting point -- thank you! what if I needed to compute the "musts" (your `m1` and `m2` above) on the fly? As in, there might be 3 of them or 1 of them and I have to compose them separately depending on what filters are passed in? Would an empty array in the `Must` definition match all documents or only documents that had those fields empty? Thanks again for your great answer so far.

Comment: You can define list of filters first then pass it to Bool, I updated the answer.  For empty array case, it will be suppress by NEST and it equal to match all.

Comment: FYI If you want to query for fields with empty values, you can try `missing` filter (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html)

Comment: The update was exactly what I needed to see. Thanks so much for taking the time to clarify.